# Why I cannot run background process by "at now < jobsfile" on Mac?

Tags: macos, process

I can run a process in background by

```
$ someprog > logfile &
```

but if I do

```
$ at now < jobsfile
```

then nothing happens except printing

```
job 1 at Wed Sep 29 19:12:40 2010
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atrun` is disabled by default in Mac OS X 10.6 (see its man page, and the "IMPLEMENTATION NOTES" section of the `at` man page).  To enable it, run:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

P.s. you might want to check and/or clear out the queue of jobs first; otherwise it'll fire off all the test jobs you submitted at once...  `atq` and `atrm` are the relevant commands (and they work fine before enabling `atrun`).

Answer (score 0):

What does jobsfile do? If it sends output to stdout or stdin, that will be mailed to you.

Comment: `jobsfile` contains `someprog > logfile`. It is a very long calculation run via `PVM` (22 processes). I don't see any activity in the second case, and the `logfile` is not created.

Comment: @Andrei: You don't see any activity where? `at` runs the job without a tty. Does this work?: `echo 'date > /tmp/at.$$.out' | at now` It should create a file called `/tmp/at.PID.out` (where "PID" is some number) which contains a date/time. Also, does `at now -f jobsfile` (instead of redirection) work?

Comment: No result in both cases. The first printed `job 2 at Wed Sep 29 22:49:40 2010`, the second printed `at: garbled time`. This happens in OS X 10.6.4.